# Range not found when passing argument in getRangeList

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to change the font of some ranges in bold

To gain time I want to use the function getRangeList to modify all ranges at the same time

I detect the list of ranges to modify with a loop and concatenate them in a variable like this:

```
for(i = 0; i <= mytab.length -1; i++){
    if(condition){
      if(coord == ''){
        coord = coord + '\'A' + i + '\'' + ', \'F' + i + '\'';
      }
      else{
        coord = coord + ', \'A' + i + '\'' + ', \'F' + i + '\''; 
      }
    }
  }
```

The `Logger.log(coord)` looks as follow:

```
10:56:48 AM Notice  Execution started
10:56:58 AM Info    'A3', 'F3', 'A6', 'F6', 'A8', 'F8', 'A12', 'F12', 'A18', 'F18'
```

The issue appears when I try to use my coord variable with getRangeList

```
sheet.getRangeList([coord]).setFontWeight('bold');
```

returns "Exception: Range not found"

But when I manually write all of the values in the function it works.

```
sheet.getRangeList(['A3', 'F3', 'A6', 'F6', 'A8', 'F8', 'A12', 'F12', 'A18', 'F18']).setFontWeight('bold');
```

I think the issue might come from the commas not treated the same in a string variable and in the function itself but I can't manage to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array and `push` instead of string and appending the range. String looking like array is still a string and will not make it an array just because you were able put it inside between brackets.

```
coord = [];
for(i = 0; i <= mytab.length -1; i++){
  if(condition){
    coord.push(`A${i}`)
    coord.push(`F${i}`)
  }
}
// use coord directly as it is an array now
sheet.getRangeList(coord).setFontWeight('bold');
```

In your code, Range is not found because it is invalid.

`'A3', 'F3', 'A6', 'F6', 'A8', 'F8', 'A12', 'F12', 'A18', 'F18'` is counted as one element and is not a valid range.

#### Note:

- No need to use `else` coord has contents or not.